# Integrate Javascript Virtual Keyboard plugin in ck editor

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor

i am trying to integrate Javascript Virtual Keyboard plugin in ck editor.Inside of the pugin, they have given the insturctions about how to integrate it with the ck editor but still i am not able to integrate it. So can anyone help me to solve my problem.

INSTALLATION:

```
 1. Extract contents of this archive to the /plugins/ folder under CKEditor root
 2. add ",extraPlugins : 'Jsvk'" line to the editor constructor parameters
 3. Update your toolbar by adding item 'Jsvk' to one of the button groups
```

You can download the plugin from [this link](http://debugger.ru/demo/projects/virtualkeyboard/richedit/ckeditor/plugins/Jsvk/examples/sample.html)

So far, i've tried this which includes step 2 and 1 but got stuck at step3:-

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
     config.language = 'DE';
     config.extraPlugins = 'equation';
     config.extraPlugins = 'Jsvk' ; };
```

It is showing me the option of virtual keyboard but whenever i am trying to open it then it is showing me a blank popup box

Comment: And what did you try?

Comment: I did all the above steps except the last one which i really didnot able to understand .CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
 // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
  config.language = 'DE';
  config.extraPlugins = 'equation';
  config.extraPlugins = 'Jsvk' ;

Comment: You need to add that item to toolbar config. `Jsvk`

Comment: Wherer in toolbar. Can you please explain me where it is located?

Comment: `CKEDITOR.editorConfig` - `config.toolbarGroups` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `Jsvk` in `CKEDITOR.editorConfig` - `config.toolbarGroups`:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) { 
     // .....................
     config.toolbarGroups = [ 
         // .....................
         { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'Jsvk' ] }, 
         // ...............................................................^^^^^^
     ];
};
```

also change `config.extraPlugins`:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'equation, Jsvk';
```

Comment: I have written your code in config.js file but still it's not working :(

Comment: change `config.extraPlugins` also, you need to add them separated by comma not rewrite the config variable.

Comment: Yup done that and the menu toolbar appears of Jsvk but whenever i am opening it then it is showing me a blank pop up box that's it and nothing else!

Comment: Then you did not extract it correctly (1'st step). Check your errors

Comment: Well, i have extracted the Jsvk folder that was inside of rar file in ckeditor/plugins/

Comment: Did you check for errors ? PHP errors? Since you get a blank page it usually means you have an error.

Comment: Yup, i have checked for it, even inside the rar file, it also contains a sample file, opening it too showing me a blank popup box

Comment: [PHP Errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) not rar error. From my opinion this issue is solved. You have to solve your errors. Good luck

Comment: Hmm okays, will try for it

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved as it was a conflict issue with the other plugins that's why it is showing a blank pop up page.